# Is there a way to adjust the Hostrules with Cef (chrome web browser control) in winforms?

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am currently making an application with winforms and Cef (a library to get a control like the webbrowser in winforms but then chromium).

Now i'am trying to set the host rules for the chrome browser. like "--host-rules=MAP * 127.0.0.1:8000", how should i do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Quick search suggests that command line arg is not supported. https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=12036&p=22356

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#cefsettings-and-browsersettings for an example of setting command line args,  feel free to try your luck. Don't expect that host rules will work.

Comment: I have seen that source, but it was from 2009 so i was hoping that they may have added support, is there any other way how I could get the same result, with a proxy server etc?

Comment: One I linked is from 2014. Proxy server see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#proxy-resolution

Comment: So i could make a proxy server that does the dns spoofing? And then link it to the sef browser?